# Issue Getting NSData Request To Work In Swift 2.0

Tags: nsdata, nsurl, swift2

I'm hoping someone may be able to help me figure out a snafu I'm having with an app I am trying to write (or learn to write) in Swift 2.0.  This previously worked in Swift 1.2, but after the necessary conversions, I am continunally facing the error;

**Cannot invoke initializer of type 'NSData' with an argument list of type '(contenOfURL: NSURL, options: NSDataReadingOptions, error:nil)'**

Here is my code, slightly truncated, that I am using;

```
...

class func fetchMinionData() -> [Minion] {
    let myURL = "https://myurl/test.json"

    let dataURL = NSURL(string: myURL)

    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: dataURL!, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)
    //THIS IS THE LINE THAT THROWS THE ERROR

    let minionJSON = JSON(data)

    var minions = [Minion]()

    for (_ , minionDictionary) in minionJSON {
        minions.append(Minion(minionDetails: minionDictionary))
    }

    return minions
}

...
```

Note that I plan to use the [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/tree/xcode7) library to further parse the data once it is downloaded.  I am searching endlessly online, but I just can't seem to figure this out!  Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are working with Swift 2, you should not pass the last argument "error". Instead put a try around the NSData initialization. If data needs to be accessed outside take the init result in a var and convert to let Modified code

```
var optData:NSData? = nil
  do {
    optData = try NSData(contentsOfURL: dataURL!, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
  }
  catch {
    print("Handle \(error) here")
  }

  if let data = optData {
    // Convert data to JSON here
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Kedar!  Thanks for your reply.  I actually had tried that, but the issue if face is that `data` then becomes inaccessible for the rest of the function.  So if my next line after the closing `}` were `print(data)`, I receive a **Use of unresolved identifier 'data'**

Comment: Thanks, @Kedar.  At this point, I think my issue is more with SwiftyJSON than anything else.  If I print `optData`, it prints a lengthy, coded response, indicating that things are working.  If I implement `let minionJSON = JSON(data)` within the _if let data = optData_ closure, then try `print(minionJSON)`, I end up with _unknown_

Comment: Great! FYI for Swift 2 the whole idiom of passing NSError as an argument and reading its value after the call to determine success has changed. For Swift 2 all such calls are ususally change to throws. You have to implement  the catch block to trap any error

Answer (score 0):

Example code for Dictionary :) Swift 2.0 
https://github.com/DaRkD0G/LoadExtension/edit/master/LoadExtensionDictionary.swift

```
enum EHError: ErrorType {
    case Nil(String)
    case NSData(String)
    case JSON(String) 
}
extension Dictionary {

        /**
        Loads a JSON file from the app bundle into a new dictionary

        - parameter filename: File name

        - throws: PathForResource / NSData / JSON

        - returns: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
        */
        static func loadJSONFromBundle(filename: String) throws ->  Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

            guard let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(filename, ofType: "json")  else {
                throw EHError.Nil("[EasyHelper][loadJSONFromBundle][->pathForResource] The file could not be located\nFile : '\(filename).json'")
            }

            guard let data = try? NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options:NSDataReadingOptions())   else {
               throw EHError.NSData("[EasyHelper][loadJSONFromBundle][->NSData] The absolute path of the file not find\nFile : '\(filename)'")
            }

            guard let jsonDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions()) as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> else {
                throw EHError.JSON("[EasyHelper][loadJSONFromBundle][->NSJSONSerialization]Error.InvalidJSON Level file '\(filename)' is not valid JSON")


            }

            return jsonDict

        }
}
```

If I do not do a mistake, for you is that

```
/**
Loads a JSON file from the app bundle into a new dictionary

- parameter filename: File name

- throws: EHError : PathForResource / NSData / JSON

- returns: [String : AnyObject] 
*/
static func loadJSONFromBundle(filename: String, nameJson:String) throws ->  [String : AnyObject] {

    guard let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(filename, ofType: "json")  else {
        throw EHError.Nil("[EasyHelper][loadJSONFromBundle][->pathForResource] The file could not be located\nFile : '\(filename).json'")
    }

    guard let data = try? NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options:NSDataReadingOptions())   else {
        throw EHError.NSData("[EasyHelper][loadJSONFromBundle][->NSData] The absolute path of the file not find\nFile : '\(filename)'")
    }

    guard let jsonDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .AllowFragments) as? [String : AnyObject] else {
        throw EHError.JSON("[EasyHelper][loadJSONFromBundle][->NSJSONSerialization] Invalid JSON\n nameJson '\(nameJson)'\nFile '\(filename)'")
    }



    return jsonDict

}
```